# How to place widgets according to different sized computer screens in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to place widgets that will change it's position when I resize the window. This works well with .pack. But, I can't place widgets very well with it. Hence, I want to use .place. However, the widget stays in the same position even when I try to resize the window. Is there any way I can solve this?

Comment: you are looking for layouts, You may also use grid or pack. you can also use a layout within another layout. It works pretty well.

Comment: This question is far too broad. `pack`, `place`, and `grid` can all be used to add widgets to the window and have them be responsive.

Comment: How can I make place and grid responsive? When I resize my window they stay in their fixed positions

Comment: Please provide a simple but complete [mcve] that shows what you've tried. Grid has many options which control whether widgets grow and shrink, and whether the rows and columns they are placed in will grow or shrink.

Comment: Concerning to the title of this question: I experienced the following. I created with tkinter a python script with widgets and I placed them all with "place". Then I ran it on annother computer but there all widgets are overlapped. How can I solve this without correcting all coordinates in "place" to reposition all widgets properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.place()`, for example a button will resize when you resize the window.

```
myButton = Button(root, text="Press Me!")
myButton.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2, relwidth=0.4, relheight=0.7)
```

`relx` Is the relative *x* position, as you resize the window, the x position will change accordingly

`rely` Is the same as above but for the *y* position

`relwidth` This is the relative *width* of the button, this changes when the window resizes

`relheight` Is the same but for the *height*

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. I'm sort of new to tkinter so I didn't know about this one. Helped a lot

Comment: Please can you add this as the answer if it worked